# {exp:rest} - Dynamically access keys

Tags: rest

I am using the [**Rest plugin**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/rest).

Let us say that my API outputs a JSON like this

```
{
  "8741" : "some data 1 ...",
  "27848" : "some data 2 ...",
  ...
}
```

I want to access the data via its index. I will know what the index is at runtime.
So how do I access the data?

```
{exp:rest ...}
 {8741}  <-- can't define this literally since the index is going to be set at runtime
{/exp:rest}
```

Comment: Is this using the rest module here? http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/rest If so, I'm not sure there's a way to get at that data without modifying the add-on.